# Using a Command in multiple Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Is it possible to define a Command in one plugin and use it at another plugin?

Thanks Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Commands are designed as abstractions. They can be found with their ids and can be used in other plugins. You don't even have to depend on the plugin that defines the command.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible by adding the plugin which has the Command to the dependencies of the other plugin in which you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a dependency to the plug-in defining the command.

As soon as the command is declared, it is made known to the `ICommandService` which is provided by the workbench.